# how to find first, second and third largest values from different columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have a table with columns J1,J2,J3,J4,J5,J6,J7. I want to find the largest 3 values from these columns as L1,L2,L3.

I tried the below query to find the first largest

```
SELECT (
    SELECT Max(v) FROM (
        VALUES 
          ([J1]), ([J2]), 
          ([J3]), ([J4]),
          ([J5]), ([J6]),
          ([J7])
    ) AS value(v)
) as [L1]FROM dbo.JTable
```

Comment: Is there a PK in the table?

Comment: PL/SQL is Oracle's language for stored procedures. SQL Server is a completely different DBMS. So what are you _really_ using? Oracle or SQL Server? Judging from the example, it's SQL Server and not Oracle

Comment: Generally a sign of a broken data model - all values of the same "type" (such that it's meaningful to compare two such values, or compute aggregates upon them) ought to be in *one* column. And then there ought to be an additional column if the numbers 1-7 are actually meaningful *data* that has become embedded in your column names.

Comment: I tried the query Mr.Giorgos given, But not providing the desired result. Any suggestion on this query?
    SELECT id, [1], [2], [3].....,[7], [8] INTO TEMP6
    FROM ( SELECT id, Val, rn
    FROM (SELECT id, Val, Col,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY Val DESC ) AS rn
    FROM TEMP5
    UNPIVOT ( Val FOR Col IN ([Week1],
    [Week2],[Week3],[Week4].....[Week53]
    )) AS unpvt) AS t
    WHERE t.rn <= 8) AS src
    PIVOT (MAX(Val) FOR rn IN ([1], [2],..., [7], [8])) AS pvt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your table has a PK, say `id`, then you can use a query that employees [**`UNPIVOT`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY Val) AS rn
  FROM JTable
  UNPIVOT (
     Val FOR Col IN (J1, J2, J3, J4, J5, J6, J7)) AS unpvt) AS t
WHERE t.rn <= 3
```

If you want one row per `id`, then you can use `PIVOT` to undo the `UNPIVOT` operation:

```
SELECT id, [1], [2], [3]
FROM (
  SELECT id, Val, rn
  FROM (
    SELECT id, Val, Col,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY Val) AS rn
    FROM JTable
    UNPIVOT (
       Val FOR Col IN (J1, J2, J3, J4, J5, J6, J7)) AS unpvt) AS t
  WHERE t.rn <= 3) AS src
PIVOT (
   MAX(Val) FOR rn IN ([1], [2], [3])) AS pvt
```

Comment: It is not fetching the top 3 values, I modified the query a bit since I need to have top 8 values from a list of 53 columns and it has more than 2000 rows . Below is the query I used for `     SELECT id, [1], [2], [3].....,[7], [8] INTO TEMP6
    FROM ( SELECT id, Val, rn
    FROM (SELECT id, Val, Col,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY Val DESC ) AS rn
    FROM TEMP5
    UNPIVOT ( Val FOR Col IN ([Week1],
    [Week2],[Week3],[Week4].....[Week53]
    )) AS unpvt) AS t
    WHERE t.rn <= 8) AS src
    PIVOT (MAX(Val) FOR rn IN ([1], [2],..., [7], [8])) AS pvt`